# In play writing, script writing or theatre is there a name for some exchange of dialogue between characters that is supposed to make a point?

Tags: character-development, screenwriting, playwriting

Suppose you want to show that two characters have some animosity towards one another. In some scene you set up a meeting between the characters in the elevator and an exchange of lines occurs. This develops as some kind of important factor that sets up the story in "Act 1: The Beginning". The exchange itself plays a significant role in Act 1 as do other scenes similar to it.

Is there a name for this exchange of dialogue?

PS. You can imagine this another way. In stand up comedy, sometimes, the comedian may chose to act out some funny situation between two or more characters that he plays out himself, taking turns to impersonate each character. This play is usually short, and has to have a very defined "conclusion" or gag. Is there a name for this exchange once it has made its point?

Comment: Should there ever be writing that _isn't_ trying to make a point?

Comment: Reading this title I was hoping to find a discussion of ethos.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by *make a point*. Following from the principle of [Chekhov's gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chekhov%27s_gun) every element in a play should have a dramatic purpose.

> "One must never place a loaded rifle on the stage if it isn't going to
>   go off. It's wrong to make promises you don't mean to keep." Chekhov,
>   letter to Aleksandr Semenovich Lazarev  1 November 1889

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the phrase "to make a point" throws me off a little, but it sounds like you're describing exposition.